# SSIS Condition: How to get results from the past 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a condition in my SSIS package that will only grab my data if it was from the last 24 hours.  I have a column named DateObtained which is a datetime data type.  I'm inserting data, and every time I do, it creates the datetime of that insert.

My issue is in an SSIS package.  I am creating a conditional split that I would like to only grab data from if it was from the last 24 hours.  So far I have what is below, I know the issue is in my DATEDIFF, but I cant solve this.

The DateObtained column comes back as 2016-12-11 12:12:12.000.

Thanks in advance.

```
DateObtained < GETDATE() &&  [DateObtained] > DATEDIFF("Day", -1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return results where the DateObtained is greater than or equal to the current date minus 24 hours. In other words, the past 24 hours.

```
DateObtained >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

I hope this helps!

**Documentation:**

[DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)